# JQUERY: Finding by control ID

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Currently my aspx page contains

```
<input type="text" name="openid_username" />
<input type="text" name="openid_identifier" />
```

but now i would like to replace them with

```
<asp:TextBox ID="openid_username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="openid_identifier" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

so how should i modify the following JQUERY, to reflect the input boxes to textboxes replacement?

```
  var $usr = $this.find('input[name=openid_username]');
  var $id = $this.find('input[name=openid_identifier]');
```

Comment: Check the generated HTML. What are the new ID:s that are generated by ASP.NET?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the "ends with" option on the attribute selector in case the name is mangled by the control being in a container.  Note the `$=` instead of `=`.

```
var $usr = $this.find('input[name$=openid_username]');
var $id = $this.find('input[name$=openid_identifier]');
```

Comment: Edit: nvm! they are not `input` anymore, they are `textbox`es now. also they dont have the `name` property anymore.

Comment: @moe - `asp:TextBox` translates to an HTML input element.  They are also given both a name and ID property by the framework.

Comment: This is better solution. Asp Text Box is rendered as input, but as tvanfosson wrote here, you must be cautious if it's placed in some of the containers its id will be prefixed by container Id. (unless you use .net 4.0 where you can control this)

Comment: @nemke - I no longer use WebForms but had heard that you had more control over the naming container.  If so, you could certainly have more confidence that the container wouldn't change on you.  "Ends with" -- as long as you don't have multiple instances of the control on the page -- should still work.

Comment: @moe You should learn a bit of asp.net and html. Textbox does not exist as html element. Here you can read how is asp textbox rendered http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/04/27/ASPNET-for-web-designers-Introduction.aspx

Comment: @tvanfosson I also use this like you wrote. I have just recalled an issue with some Devexpress controls they used to put sufix for id, so not even jquery could help, not the God almighty :)

Comment: @nemke - "contains" `*=` is another option but more limiting in the sense that you have to be more careful not to have conflicts between your ids, e.g. `*='userid'` matches both `userid` and `update_userid`.

Comment: Just adding to @tvanfosson's answer, make sure to read this article by Dave Ward, to improve the solutions performance, just by adding additional parameters to help jQuery obtain the targets faster.

http://encosia.com/11-keystrokes-that-made-my-jquery-selector-run-10x-faster/

Answer (score 3):

If you want the exact ID of your controls, you can do this:

```
var $usr = $this.find('#<%= openid_username.ClientID %>');
var $id = $this.find('#<%= openid_identifier.ClientID %>');
```

Of course, this is assuming your JS isn't in an external file.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var $usr=$("#openid_username");
```

should work or try

```
 var $usr = $('[id*=openid_username]');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but if ID translates into the elements ID attribute (i.e turns into `<input type="text" id="openid_username">` in the aspx generated html, I would go with:

```
var $usr = $("#openid_username");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $usr = $this.find('#openid_username');
var $id = $this.find('#openid_identifier');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following to achieve that:

```
var $usr = $("input[id$='openid_username']");
var $id = $("input[id$='openid_identifier']");
```