# can we set Label ID using Eval block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQUERY: Finding by control ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370716/jquery-finding-by-control-id)

as i am trying set label id using `<%# Eval("SomeColumnName") %>`. i wonder is it possible? i need to give LabelID with Some Suffix, like UserID.

eg : `<asp:Label Id="ss_<%# Eval("UserID") %>" runat="server" />`

i have placed this in gridview. so it will generate random id, based on the container_control_somerow_someID format, i thought will assign UserID at the end of the so that it will be unique. then i can easily get the  client id easily, by using indexof method.

i have a label in gridview, and beside of label i have a button. whenever i click the button, i need to send the label text or id.

is it possible ? right now it is giving error, as Asp.net markup are not well formed. if not possible can any body tell me, what is the reason behind this to not allowed to assign like this ?

can anybody tell me ?

Comment: the requirement of gridview can be done in another way...but i have no answer for setting labelid from user id..

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an asp:Label and runat=server? If not you could do it with a plain label (or span).

```
<label id='ss_<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
```

Note the quotes.

Comment: i need run at server, as it needs to done in code behind

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you can use RowCommand of ASP.NET will help

```
<asp:GridView id="grdCommodityTypeSize" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
  AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
  DataKeyNames="nCommodityTypeSizeID" EnableViewState="False" Width="500px" 
  DataSourceID="odsCommodityTypeSize" PageSize="8" 
  OnRowDataBound="grdCommodityTypeSize_RowDataBound" 
  OnRowUpdating="grdCommodityTypeSize_RowUpdating" 
  OnRowDeleted="grdCommodityTypeSize_RowDeleted" 
  OnRowUpdated="grdCommodityTypeSize_RowUpdated" 
  OnRowCommand="grdCommodityTypeSize_RowCommand"> 
<asp:Button ID="btnTypeSizeCommodity1" runat="server" Text="Go" 
  CommandName="Go" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("nCommodityTypeSizeID") %>' /> 
</asp:GridView>
```

and in the code behind you can go for

```
 if (e.CommandName.ToUpper() == "GO") 
    { 
        int _rowIndex = -1; 
        Button btn = (Button)e.CommandSource; 
        for (int i = 0; i < grdCommodityTypeSize.DataKeys.Count; i++) 
        { 
            if (Convert.ToInt32(grdCommodityTypeSize.DataKeys[i].Value) == 
                      Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)) 
            { 
                _rowIndex = i; 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
        if (_rowIndex > -1) 
        { 
            //ur code

        } 
    }
```

you will get the row from which button is clicked. You can get the row and manipulate watever u want.

Comment: no.. i know this. i think you not understood. i need to set label id unique. is it possible to use Eval or not ? i know rowcommand events

Comment: i dbt we can use Eval for runat=server